# Is there a difference in performance whether I put the trailing comma in array or not?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, jvm

In the "Thinking in Java" book 4th edition I read that leaving the comma after the last object in list **makes automatic generating such lists easier, but it is optional**. On the other hand [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html), in the Java SE Specifications I can read, that the **trailing comma is ignored**. On StackOverflow questions I read that it makes code **easier to maintain**.

Does it make any difference on the JVM work? I deduce that it's only a good practice, am I right? If there is no difference in performance, should I use it as default? Which version is used in practice more frequently?

Here is a sample code to show the problem:

```
Integer[] arrFst = new Integer[]{new Integer(1), new Integer(2), };
Integer[] arrSnd = new Integer[]{new Integer(1), new Integer(2) };
```

Comment: `difference in performance` - try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Thinking in Java book 4th edition I read, that leaving the comma after the last object in list makes automatic generating such lists easier, but it is optional.

Correct.

> On the other hand here, in Java SE Specifications I can read, that trailing comma is ignored.

Correct, but there's no 'on the other hand' about it. It's ignored. By the compiler. There is no conflict between the above two statements.

> On StackOverflow questions I read that it makes code easier to maintain.

Correct again.

> But I would like to ask you if it makes any difference for the JVM work?

No, because it's ignored by the compiler, so the JVM doesn't even get to see it.

> I deduce that it's only a good practice, am I right?

It's an optional practice that is useful in certain situations.

> If there is no difference in performance, should I use it as default?

No, why?

> Which version is used in practice more frequently?

That isn't answerable without a complete survey of all the Java code in existence, or enough of it to constitute a statistically significant sample. And in any case you should do what is best for you, not what everybody does statistically speaking.

Comment: I still don't get how to decide which version should I use, but your answer really helped me. Thanks!